# Amazon Athena group by column and create array/list column

Tags: amazon-athena

In athena I have data as below

```
a b
1 2
1 3
1 5
2 6
```

My desired output is below

```
a  test_col

1  [2,3,5]

2  [6]
```

How do I perform in athena.

Answer (score 3):

I tried with below code it worked thank you

```
select a,array_agg(b)
from <your table name>
group by a
```

Thank you, if any one have attempted this .

Answer (score 0):

If you have data like the following:

[image]

```
SELECT 
    loan_id,
    emi,
    array_agg(ARRAY [f1,f2,f3,f4,f5]) as d -- This operation can be automated with a template
  FROM table_name
GROUP BY loan_id, emi
```

The output is like:

[image]

Something trivial! But I couldn't find such solution. Hope it helps someone someday.